# Scrapy only outputting an open bracket

Tags: python, url, web-crawler, scrapy, scrape

I'm trying to scrape the title and URL of all khan academy pages under the math/science/economics pages. However, currently it is only outputting an open bracket, and before this happened it would only scrape the start URL.

```
from openbar_index.items import OpenBarIndexItem
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor


class OpenBarSpider(CrawlSpider):
    """
    scrapes website URLs from educational websites and commits urls/webpage names/text to a document
    """

    name = 'openbar'
    allowed_domains = 'khanacademy.org'
    start_urls = [

        "https://www.khanacademy.org"

    ]

     rules = [

            Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow = ['/math/']), callback='parse_item', follow = True),
             Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow = ['/science/']), callback='parse_item', follow=True),
             Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow = ['/economics-finance-domain/']), callback='parse_item', follow=True)
    ]

    def parse_item(self, response):

         item = OpenBarIndexItem()
         url = response.url
         item['url'] = url
         item['title'] = response.xpath('/html/head/title/text()').extract()
         yield item
```

Does anyone have an idea why this is happening or tips on how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the assignment to `allowed_domains`. This must not be a `string` but a `list` according to the [documentation](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/0.24/topics/spiders.html?highlight=allowed_domains#scrapy.spider.Spider.allowed_domains). With the string the potentially results are filtered by scrapy as offsite requests because there is no valid domain.

So adding square brackets like in next line should fix it

```
    allowed_domains = ['khanacademy.org']
```